# SFML image extension for best performance

Tags: opengl, c++, sfml

I am using [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) library in my 2D game.

The [Texture Class](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/classsf_1_1Texture.php) has a method to load an image from file:

```
Texture.loadFromFile("image.*")
```

Which file extension should I use to achieve best performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Original texture format does not affect in game performance

There may be a small loading time difference, but that is likely dependent on what system you are running on.

**Use what ever texture format you and your artists are comfortable with. I would personally use png because it is losslessly compressed.**

Don't fret over a few milliseconds on texture loading, you are likely to save more time by using your own sprite sheets.

**If you really want to figure it out, profile all the different image loading techniques.**